# Flutter webrtc - PlatformException(mediaStream AddTrack: Stream is null, null, null, null)

Tags: flutter, webrtc

I'm working on the call function with Flutter WebRTC, and I encountered a situation where there are no issues between Android devices, no issues between Android and iOS virtual devices, and no issues between iOS virtual devices and real iOS devices. However, when it comes to a real iOS device and an Android device, an error occurs: 'PlatformException(mediaStream AddTrack: Stream is null, null, null, null).' I have tried various methods to fix it, but I haven't been successful. If anyone knows a solution, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.[image]

Comment: Do you have any solution for it?